# Link an "external" file in docsify

Tags: docsify

This is my documentation files structure

```
|__docs/
| |__config-docsify.js
| |__index.html
| |__README.md
|__README.md
```

As you can see, the Docsify files are in `docs/` directory and I would like to link the `/docs/README.md` file to root the README file (`/README.md`). I.e., when I click on a link in the `/docs/README.md` file, I get redirected to `/README.md` file, or at least I get its content somehow.

However, when I try to add a link like this

```
<!-- projectfolder/docs/README.md file -->
See the [README](../README.md) file in the root directory.
```

I get redirected to `localhost:3000/../README.md` which does not exist.

Does anyone know a way to link a file that is not in the same folder (or subfolder) of the docsify files?

---

#### EDIT

I am serving the `docs` folder using

```sh
docsify serve docs/
```

Comment: Have a look at this, it might help: https://docsify.now.sh/configuration?id=relativepath

Comment: @alcaprar I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. I tried to combine with `basePath` but nothing. Maybe the file is out of reach because docsify is serving the folder that is in the same level as the file I am trying to open. What do you think about it?

Comment: Yes I think you are right. Docsify should serve everything is inside the docs folder (everything is at the same level of index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can embed external files (or raw.github...) using embed files: https://docsify.js.org/#/embed-files

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't work. I updated the question to say that I am serving the `docs` directory. Maybe that is the reason it can't get the README file. They are both in the same level.

Comment: If this is hosted on guthub, you could get the raw instead of including using the file path. So, your path may look something like: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<user>/<repo>/master/README.md`

Comment: @Blizzard This works and it even gets mentioned in the docs, however it only works once the documentation is hosted online. You cannot test it with live preview on your local system.

Comment: I am able to test this just fine with `docsify serve /path/to/site` and then navigating to the local address.